# Get the logged in user's NT ID from Java server

Tags: java, spring

I am going to host my application in a server. I just want to get the NT ID of the user, who logs into  my application. Kindly share if any one having answer?

`system.getremoteUser()` and `system.getProperty` will return the hosted machine name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are specific about NT ID fetching in `Java`, this might work

```
com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem NTSystem = new
            com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem();
    System.out.println(NTSystem.getName());
    System.out.println(NTSystem.getDomain());
    System.out.println(NTSystem.getUserSID());
```

But for a webapplication context where you have NTLM authentication, you should be having NTLM (Windows) users as your application users as-well (this is a general case).

It would be better to query NTLMRealm (in Tomcat) or store user identity (SID etc) in a context (this can be session based or specific custom server-side implementation) while authenticating user via NTLM. Now use this context to retrieve NTLM properties of users (SID, GroupID etc) logged-in.